# Re-use YAML sections

Tags: yaml

I'm putting together a docker-compose file. I'd like to re-use sections that are repetitive. For example, each container re-uses the same `deploy` config. I tried making a template for it:

```
  ...
  redis:
    image: redis
    ports:
      - 6379:6379
    deploy: deploy_template
    volumes:
      - /srv/redis/data:/data

deploy_template:
  restart_policy:
    condition: on-failure
    delay: 5s
    max_attempts: 10
    window: 120s
```

However this didn't work. Is there any way to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use the YAML anchor and alias facility for that, effectively:

```
version: '2'
dummy: &deploy_template
  restart_policy:
    condition: on-failure
    delay: 5s
    max_attempts: 10
    window: 120s
services:
  redis:
    image: redis
    ports:
      - 6379:6379
    deploy: *deploy_template
    volumes:
      - /srv/redis/data:/data
```

will be parsed as if you had specified:

```
version: '2'
dummy:
  restart_policy:
    condition: on-failure
    delay: 5s
    max_attempts: 10
    window: 120s
services:
  redis:
    image: redis
    ports:
    - 6379:6379
    deploy:
      restart_policy:
        condition: on-failure
        delay: 5s
        max_attempts: 10
        window: 120s
    volumes:
    - /srv/redis/data:/data
```

You can have multipe `*deploy_template` values for a single `&deploy_template` anchor.

The problem however is that the `dummy` key, and its value, will trip `docker-compose`, and at least in version 2 there was no place to put this information.

I therefore preprocess my `docker-compose` file using [`ruamel.dcw`](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/ruamel.dcw) (I am the author of that package), which allows for a `user-data` top-level key that will not appear in the output and where you can put such anchor information. Starting with:

```
version: '2'
user-data:
  author: dthree <calvin@hobbes.org>
  description: redis container
  env-defaults:
    NAME: redis  # default values if not specified in the environment
    PORT: 6379
  dummy: 
  - &deploy_template
    restart_policy:
      condition: on-failure
      delay: 5s
      max_attempts: 10
      window: 120s
  - &some_other_template:
    x: null
services:
  redis:
    image: ${NAME}
    ports:
      - "${PORT}:${PORT}"
    deploy: *deploy_template
    volumes:
      - /srv/${NAME}/data:/data
```

this will expand to:

```
version: '2'
services:
  redis:
    image: ${NAME}
    ports:
    - ${PORT}:${PORT}
    deploy:
      restart_policy:
        condition: on-failure
        delay: 5s
        max_attempts: 10
        window: 120s
    volumes:
    - /srv/${NAME}/data:/data
```

before being handed to `docker-compose` itself (using the `-f` option). Any variables in the `env-defaults` "section" that are not already set in the environment in which you execute the preprocessor, will be given their default value, making it easy to override them.

As an aside: you should be careful with:

```
 - 6379:6379
```

because if the port number gets below 60, the old YAML parser that docker-compose uses, interprets that scalar as a sexagesimal. I tend to always quote such values, especially when using env. variables.